# Loading my private key for use in git on Mac

Tags: git, macos, private-key

I'm trying to use git on a Mac (I'm a Mac newbie.) I obviously have to load my private key. On my Windows machine I just use pageant and msysgit. How do I load my private key into git on the Mac?

Answer (score 1):

If you open the key with `PuTTY Key Generator`, you can export your key in the OpenSSH format.  Just copy that to your mac and put it as a file named `id_rsa` in your `~/.ssh` directory (which you'll have to create if you haven't run ssh-keygen).

[image: Export OpenSSH key]

If it's not too much trouble though you can just use `ssh-keygen` to create a new key pair and add the new `id_rsa.pub` public key to the account you're accessing.  Most online git repositories and ssh hosts (like Winsshd) allow you to link multiple keys to an account.

Comment: Great reply but the question was for Mac.

Comment: He specifically asks about using the private key generated using putty and using putty to export it into a format your mac can use seems reasonable to me.  I also have a paragraph at the bottom about using `ssh-keygen` if he wants to create a new key on  his mac...

Answer (score 0):

I'd say just create a new key. If you're posting to github it's no big deal to push two public keys up, and same for putting it up on another server - it's just another entry in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys.

The github guide localshred pointed to should have all the directions you'd need.